# Plotting functions with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, plot, axis, function

I would like to be able to plot standard function in Tikz, for a document in LaTeX I'm writing.

So far, I tried and I used this piece of code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-5, 0) -- (5, 0) node[right] {$\vu*{x}$};
\draw[->] (0, -3) -- (0, 5) node[above] {$\vu*{y}$};
\draw[scale=0.5, domain=-3:3, smooth, variable=\x, red]  plot ({\x}, {3});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here I just wanted to plot a constant function.

Now, this is bad, but works (with few modifications).

I am asking you for this: how can I add the ticks labels on the axis? Both in $x$ and $y$ axis, in unit steps? Like $0, 1, 2, 3$ and so on, on the axis (the negative too)?

Also, how can I add dotted, or dashed, ends in the plotted function?

Thank you so much!

**ADD**

Ok, solved the second problem by adding:

```
\draw[scale=0.5, domain=-5.5:-4.5, thick, dashed, variable=\x,      black] plot ({\x}, {3});
\draw[scale=0.5, domain=4.5:5.5, thick, dashed, variable=\x, black] plot ({\x}, {3});
```

**ADD 2**

My document preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={173mm, 257mm}, left=23mm, top=23mm, right=23mm,     bottom=23mm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

%\usepackage{newtxtext}

```
\usepackage[bb=stixtwo]{mathalpha}

\usepackage{concmath}



\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {datavisualization.formats.functions}
\usepackage{pspicture}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Where is defined `\vu`? Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your picture, which we can compile as it s.

Comment: Graphing functions is ususally done using pgfplots or tikz data visualization (page 851).

Comment: @Zarko Oh, sorry, this comes from the Physics package! It writes unit vectors with the bold style and with a hat.

Comment: @Numb3rs, how should I know this= I don't use this package ... So I ask you to provide MWE (Minimal Working Example) that we can see document preamble. My crystal ball is similarly as at other members, who are willing to help you, quite foggy ... :-(

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm reading that part on the manual, and it looks like promising and helpful. I don't understand how to thicken the axis and the curve, though...

Comment: @Numb3rs, you now already got  an answer with two possible solutions ...

Comment: @Zarko Yes, but I was asking for the "Data Visualisation" mode, as a one more tool

Comment: @Numb3rs, no you not. According to your comment, your question is not clear what you after.

Answer (score 2):

With pure `tikz` can be something like this:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[> = Straight Barb,
ticklabel/.style = {fill=white, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt, anchor=#1}
                        ]
\draw[->] (-5, 0) -- (5, 0) node[right] {$X$};
\draw[->] (0, -2) -- (0, 4) node[above] {$Y$};
\foreach \i in {-4, -3,...,4}
    \draw   (\i,0.1) -- ++ (0,-0.2) node[ticklabel=north] {\i};
\foreach \i in {-1, 1,2,3}
    \draw   (0.1,\i) -- ++ (-0.2,0) node[ticklabel=east] {\i};
\scoped[on background layer]
\draw[domain=-4:4, samples=2, thick]  plot (\x, 3);

\draw[domain=-5:-4, samples=2, thick, dashed]  plot (\x, 3);
\draw[domain= 4: 5, samples=2, thick, dashed]  plot (\x, 3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
However, for such diagrams is usually used `pgfplots package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    axis on top,
    label style = {anchor=north east},
    xlabel = $x$,   ylabel = $y$,
    xmin=-5,    xmax = 5,
    ymin=-2,    ymax = 5,
    ytick = {-1,1,2,3,4},
    ticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize, fill=white, inner sep=2pt},
    samples=2, no marks,
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick, color=blue}
                        ]
\addplot  [domain = -5:-3, dashed] {3};
\addplot  [domain = -3:3] {3};
\addplot  [domain =  3:5, dashed] {3};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Writing correct symbols for axis I left to you (sorry, you not provide MWE: Minimal Working example, that I can see Your document preamble).

Answer (score 2):

Like this (with more 2 functions):

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[gray!20](-4,-4) grid (4,4); % grid
        
        % function(s) to plot in the next lines
        \draw[magenta,domain=-4:4,line width=2pt] plot (\x,3);
        \draw[smooth,cyan,domain=-pi:pi,line width=2pt] plot (\x,{sin(3*\x r)+\x});
        \draw[smooth,dotted,domain=-pi:pi,line width=1pt] plot (\x,\x);
        
        % x & y axis plus scale
        \foreach \x in {-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4}{
            \draw (\x,.1)--(\x,-.1) node[below]() {\footnotesize $\x$};
            \draw (.1,\x)--(-.1,\x) node[left,fill=white]() {\footnotesize $\x$};
            }
        \draw[->,line width=.5pt] (-4,0)-- (4.5,0) node[below]() {$x$};
        \draw[->,line width=.5pt] (0,-4)-- (0,4.5) node[right]() {$y$};
        \node at(.2,-.2) () {\footnotesize O};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```